# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning--unclear about course of action

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting these lint errors

```
./components/create-nft/InstagramSelector.js
39:15  Warning: Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. Put the async function inside:

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state

Learn more about data fetching with Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/hooks-data-fetching  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

If I look at line 39, it begins with this:

```
    useEffect(async () => {
        console.log("on mount")

        if (localStorageApi.isLoggedInIg()) {
            setLoggedIn(true)
        }
        else {
            setLoggedIn(false)
        }

    }, [])
```

localStorageApi, is just a wrapper around localStorage, which is synchronous. setLoggedIn, is the useState setter

next is this warning:

```
56:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getIgMedia'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Line 56 is the last line here:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (loggedIn) {
            (async () => await getIgMedia())()
        }
        
    }, [loggedIn])
```

I don't understand what I am supposed to do here.  I want the function to trigger when there is a change with "loggedIn".  I don't want it to trigger with any other dependency.

Comment: If you truly don't want it to trigger with other dependencies then ignore the error, otherwise if `getIgMedia` doesn't change you can safely add it as a dep after wrapping into a `useCallback`

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your post correctly, you have React hook warnings with 2 `useEffect` hooks you are using.

1. Warning: Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions.

   > ```
   > useEffect(async () => {
   >   console.log("on mount");
   >
   >   if (localStorageApi.isLoggedInIg()) {
   >     setLoggedIn(true);
   >   } else {
   >     setLoggedIn(false);
   >   }
   > }, []);
   > ```

   The issue here, and what the warning is pointing out, is that React hook callbacks are synchronous functions. You've passed an `async` function. `async` functions implicitly return a Promise, which can cause issues when React assumes, incorrectly, that this returned value is a cleanup function.

   Normally you would declare the `async` function inside the callback and invoke it, e.g.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     const getLoggedInState = async () => {
       console.log("on mount");
       setLoggedIn(localStorageApi.isLoggedInIg());
     };

     getLoggedInState();
   }, []);
   ```

   but since there's not actually any asynchronous code and no use of `await` there is no need for the function to be declared `async`, e.g.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log("on mount");
     setLoggedIn(localStorageApi.isLoggedInIg());
   }, []);
   ```
2. Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getIgMedia'.

   > ```
   > useEffect(() => {
   >   if (loggedIn) {
   >     (async () => await getIgMedia())();
   >   } 
   > }, [loggedIn]);
   > ```

   The issue here is that `getIgMedia` is declared ***outside*** the `useEffect` hook's callback and referenced ***inside*** it. This makes it a dependency.

   You can either move the `getIgMedia` function declaration ***into*** the hook (*just like was done above with the first `useEffect` hook*) to remove it as an *external* dependency.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     const getIgMedia = () => { ... };

     if (loggedIn) {
       (async () => await getIgMedia())();
     } 
   }, [loggedIn]);
   ```

   Or add it to the dependency array.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     if (loggedIn) {
       (async () => await getIgMedia())();
     } 
   }, [getIgMedia, loggedIn]);
   ```

Comment: Hi Drew.  Thanks for the help.  For #1, I understand as much, but my point was that "localStorageApi.isLoggedInIg()" is not async, so Im a bit lost. This is the function:  const isLoggedInIg = () => getIgAccessToken() && getIgAccessTokenExpDate() > new Date().getTime()

As for #2, thanks for the explanation. Very clear

Comment: @Cb32019 Oh, you're right, there isn't actually any asynchronous code in the first `useEffect` hook so there's no need for an `async` function. I've updated my answer slightly.